# Populate JSP table with JSTL forEach Loop

Tags: java, foreach, jstl

My program takes an email from input, and uses the haveibeenpwned API to show the user all the breaches found from that email.

I'm wondering how I can get my `forEach` loop to populate a table properly. Currently, it just populates every item into one table row with the table header below the data. I would like the header to be on top, and each breach to be in a separate table row.

Here is my .jsp form showing the table and `forEach`:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Breach</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="breach" items="${breaches}" varStatus="status">
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">${status.count}</th>
          <td><p>${breach}</p></td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my servlet where I get an ArrayList of found breaches:

```
String json = callPwnedApi(email);

    if (json.startsWith("{") || json.startsWith("[")) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Breach> breaches = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Breach>>(){}.getType());

        if (!breaches.isEmpty() && breaches.size() > 0) {
            request.setAttribute("breaches", breaches);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So being new to JSTL, I made a very simple mistake!

I wasn't aware I needed to add the JSTL library to my project, and I also needed to add this line to my `.jsp` page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

So after doing this, my table works perfectly! Hopefully this will eventually help out someone new to JSTL!

Answer (score 0):

What error or result do you see when you run this code? [Here](https://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-jstl-tags-example) is a tutorial that has a detailed explanation of JSTL usage. As mentioned there, I think you need to qualify `breaches` as `requestScope.breaches` in the JSTL expression.

Comment: So I don't actually get an error. When I run it, all the breaches from the haveibeenpwned API populate on the page. The problem is that they should populate in the table, but for some reason they load above table. When they load, they aren't separated into different table rows, its just one long paragraph with all the breaches. So I get that big long paragraph of breaches, and then below that, is where the table loads.